# Hudson 3.2.0 breaks Maven Release Plugin

Tags: maven, hudson, maven-release-plugin

Since upgrading to Hudson 3.2.0, I am getting the following error page when using the Hudson Maven Release Plugin (0.10.0-h-1) upon pressing the "Schedule Maven Release" button:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.model.Hudson.getAuthentication()Lorg/springframework/security/Authentication;
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:607)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:650)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$12.dispatch(MetaClass.java:365)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:565)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:650)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:225)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:45)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:565)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:650)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:225)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:45)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:565)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:650)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:481)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:152)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:86)
    org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:162)
    org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:134)
    hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:89)
    org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:162)
    org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:134)
    hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:89)
    hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:78)
    hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:81)
    hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:47)
    hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:73)
    hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:156)
    hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:70)
```

Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug seems to be fixed with Hudson 3.2.1 and the new version 0.10.0-h-2 of the release plugin.